# What does $p(y|\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{\theta})=N(y|\mu(\mathbf{x}), \sigma(\mathbf{x}) )$ mean?

Tags: probability, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am learning about Linear regression with Gaussian noise, and the author wrote the statement:

$$p(y|\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{\theta})=N(y|\mu(\mathbf{x}), \sigma(\mathbf{x}) )$$

I am a bit confused here about the conditional inside the normal distribution (i.e. $y|\mu(\mathbf{x}$)). From what I know, the normal distribution is parametrized by $\mu$ and $\sigma$ but it seems here that he parametrizes it with $y$ given $\mu$?? Can someone give me a simple example of what he means here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every $y$ given $x$ can follow a different normal distribution with parameter $\mu(x)$ and $\sigma(x)$.

At $x=1$, $y|x=1$ can follow normal distribution mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$.

but at $x=2$, $y|x=2$ can follow normal distrbution with mean $\pi$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{42}.$

Comment: Right, so can I treat this as: $y|x$ is distributed by $N(\mu(x), \sigma(x))$? Or, for a given $x$, then $y$ is distributed by $N(\mu(x), \sigma(x))$ ?

Comment: your two statement are describing the same thing right?

Comment: Yes. I realize it sounds a bit confusing. What I meant was, can I interpret it using this way, or also this way (both)?

Comment: yup, that's correct.